# How do I pass the physics object between modules in the Corona Sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

main.lua

```
local physics = require("physics")
local actor = require("actor")
physics.start()

//here physic is not nil
local a = Actor.new(200, 200, physics)
```

actor.lua

```
function Actor:new(x, y, physic)
   //here physic is nil
end
```

How come I cant pass the physics object into another module?

Comment: `function Actor.new(x, y, physic)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff is this a comment on the question, or an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lua you have to be careful when you define a function in a table: do you use `.` or `:`. In `actor.lua` you define `Actor:new(x,y,phys)` which means there is an implicit `self` parameter that is available in the body of `Actor:new`; this `self` will refer to the containing `Actor` table, and is the first parameter in the call to `Actor:new`. In `main.lua` you call `Actor.new(200, 200, physics)`: note the dot instead of colon, so the first parameter is 200,  meaning `self` will be 200, `x` will be 200, and `y` will be `physics`, and `phys` will be nil. You should change the call to `new` or the definition of `new`, one or the other. For example in `main.lua`:

```
local a = Actor:new(200, 200, physics)
```

Note also that if your `actor.lua` doesn't return anything then `local actor` in `main.lua` will be `nil`. Looks like you probably defined `Actor` table as a global so you are able to reference it in `main.lua`.